# need 2 level sub menu in C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

I need to get my menu to look like this:

---

Add Relationship

```
                Brother
                Sister
                Son
                Daughter
                Mate and 
                           Son
                           Daughter
```

---

I can only get the first two.  I cannot get the code to give me the 3rd level.
Can someone give me a clue how to do this.  Here is the code I have.  I realize this code wont' work but it's the last thing I tried.

```
var item = CreateSubItem("Add Relationship");  // create instance of the sub class
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Parents", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Brother", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Sister", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Son", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Daughter", true));
var item2 = CreateSubItem("Mate And");
item2.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Son", true));
item2.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Daughter", true));
menu.Items.Add(item);
menu.Items.Add(item2);


DXSubMenuItem CreateSubItem(string caption)
{
    return new DXSubMenuItem(caption);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead of adding `item2` to the menu (top level) -

```
menu.Items.Add(item2);
```

add it as a submenu under `item` -

```
item.Items.Add(item2);
```

So the final code is -

```
var item = CreateSubItem("Add Relationship");  // create instance of the sub class
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Parents", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Brother", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Sister", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Son", true));
item.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Daughter", true));
var item2 = CreateSubItem("Mate And");
item2.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Son", true));
item2.Items.Add(CreateCheckItem("Daughter", true));

item.Items.Add(item2); # u need to add item2 to item, not the menu

menu.Items.Add(item);
```